# Hotswap-agent on JBoss EAP 6.1 - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: maven, ear, jboss-eap-6, dcevm, hotswapagent

I have an EAR project I'm deploying to Jboss EAP 6.1. The product of my maven build looks like this:

```
myapp-ear
├── myapp-ejb.jar
├── myapp-web.war
├── lib
│   ├── activation.jar
│   ├── activiti-bpmn-converter.jar
│   ├── activiti-bpmn-model.jar
.....
│   ├── xml-apis.jar
│   └── xmlbeans.jar
└── META-INF
    ├── application.xml
    ├── hotswap-agent.properties
    ├── myapp-ds.xml
    ├── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

Here's what I get in the jboss log when when I deploy my app:

```
21:34:55,570 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) HOTSWAP AGENT: 21:34:55.569 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.jbossmodules.JBossModulesPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myapp-ds.xml:main" from Service Module Loader'.
21:35:04,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "myapp-web.war")
21:35:04,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "myapp-ejb.jar")
21:35:04,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for myproject
21:35:05,306 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) HOTSWAP AGENT: 21:35:05.306 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.jbossmodules.JBossModulesPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myapp-ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader'.
```

and

```
21:35:05,488 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-6) HOTSWAP AGENT: 21:35:05.487 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myapp-ear.ear.myapp-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader'.
21:35:05,520 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-4) HOTSWAP AGENT: 21:35:05.517 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.jbossmodules.JBossModulesPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myapp-ear.ear.myapp-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader'.
```

The problem is that when I deploy my ear into jboss it takes about 10 times it's normal time and when I try to access the application from a browser it throws a "PermGen space: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space". I tired increasing my PermGen memory to 700MB but no luck. So I suspected that hotswap-agent is watching all the classes in my EAR including the ones in the lib directory which's causing it to consume too much memory.

The next place I looked into is disabling hotswap by default, by placing autoHotswap=false in hotswap-agent.properties. I tried placing this file in the EAR as shown above and the EJB and WAR classpaths but it didn't make any difference. I also tried, to no avail, adding to the JVM_OPTS like so:

```
-javaagent:/workspace/tools/hotswap-agent-1.0.jar=disablePlugin=Deltaspike,disablePlugin=JavaBeans,autoHotswap=false"
```

So my question is, how does one control the hotswap-agent in my environment? Also is there a way to only watch classes in a specified package, say "com.foobar"? Finally, what's the right way to configure hotswap-agent for an ear deployment on jboss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got hotswap-agent working in my project with the help of [Vladimir](https://github.com/skybber) in the [hotswap-agent forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hotswapagent/thGDyXbO8zk). This what he said that helped solve the runaway PermGen memory:

> JBossAS has single classLoader for each module like jar, war etc. On
>   that account there can be a lot of module classloaders in the running
>   JbossAS. Alongside HotswapAgent copies it's classes to each of that
>   module classloaders (it is necessary otherwise HotswapAgent doesn't
>   work inside module classloader).  Hence the same HotswapAgent's class
>   can be loaded by JVM multiple times ! As far as the copying of globaly
>   disabled plugin, it is bug, we should fix it. You can just remove
>   unused plugins directly from hotswap-agent.jar as a workaround, it
>   should help with performance.

Once I removed the unneeded plugins from the jar I could start jboss within reasonable time and PermGen memory.